# Resizing a dynamically allocated array of pointers (Copy Constructor not working?)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Before I ask my question let me throw down a restriction my program has:
 - not allowed to use vectors (this is for an assignment)

I'm in the process of testing my classes to make sure they do what I intended they do.  I'm trying to increase the size of a dynamically allocated array of pointers.  While debugging, I discovered that when I set pTemp[i] to pTransactions[i] the copy constructor is not being utilized; when pTransactions[i] gets deleted a few lines later, the data that should be in pTemp[i] is gone (see code below). Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Here are the related files to my question: (please let me know if you need more of the code)

Also, apologies for the lack of color in my code.  This is my very first post and I'm not entirely used to the format here. Edit: Just kidding, I see now that it just puts in the color later ...

(partial code from class Account -- pTransactions is the dynamically allocated array of pointers)

```
void Account::createNewTransaction(Transaction* newTrans) {
if (numberOfTransactions > 0) {
    //Create temp pointer
    Transaction **pTemp = new Transaction*[++numberOfTransactions];

    //Copy array to temp
    if (*pTransactions) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTransactions - 1; i++) {
            Transaction *tempTrans = pTransactions[i];
            pTemp[i] = tempTrans;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTransactions - 1; i++) {
            delete pTransactions[i];
        }
        delete[] pTransactions;
    }

    //Recreate array
    pTransactions = new Transaction*[numberOfTransactions];


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTransactions; i++) {
        pTransactions[i] = pTemp[i];
    }
}
else {
    numberOfTransactions++;
    pTransactions = new Transaction*[numberOfTransactions];
}
pTransactions[numberOfTransactions - 1] = newTrans;

double oldBalance = balance;    //Variable to hold original balance

//Complete correct type of transaction
if (newTrans == dynamic_cast<Deposit*>(newTrans))
    balance = static_cast<Deposit*>(newTrans)->makeDeposit(balance);
else if (newTrans == dynamic_cast<Withdraw*>(newTrans))
    balance = static_cast<Withdraw*>(newTrans)->makeWithdrawal(balance);
else
    balance = static_cast<Check*>(newTrans)->makeCheck(balance);

//If balance equals oldBalance -- no transaction actually occurred
if (balance == oldBalance) {
    numberOfTransactions--;
}
```

}

Transaction.ccp -- Transaction is an abstract class

```
#include "Transaction.h"

Transaction::Transaction()
{
    id = ++transactionTracker;
}

Transaction::~Transaction()
{
}

int Transaction::getTransactionTracker()
{
    return transactionTracker;
}

//Mutator Functions
void Transaction::setId(int newId) {
    id = newId;
}

void Transaction::setAmount(double amt) {
    amount = amt;
}

//Other Functions
void Transaction::cancelTransaction() {
    transactionTracker--;
}
```

Deposit.cpp -- Deposit is a derived class of Transaction

```
#include "Deposit.h"
#include <iostream>

//Constructor
Deposit::Deposit(double amt)
{
    setAmount(amt);
}

//Copy Constructor
Deposit::Deposit(const Deposit &obj)
{
    id = obj.id;
    amount = obj.amount;
}

//Deconstructor
Deposit::~Deposit()
{
}

//Functions
double Deposit::makeDeposit(double balance) {
    return balance + amount;
}

//Overloaded function (from Transaction)
void Deposit::toString() {
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Transaction #" << id << endl;
    cout << "Deposited $" << amount << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
}

//Overloaded = operator
const Deposit Deposit::operator=(const Deposit &obj)
{
    id = obj.id;
    amount = obj.amount;
    return *this;
}
```

Withdraw.cpp -- Withdraw is a derived class of Transactions

```
#include "Withdraw.h"
#include<iostream>

//Constructor
Withdraw::Withdraw(double amt)
{
    setAmount(amt);
}

//Copy Constructor
Withdraw::Withdraw(const Withdraw &obj)
{
    id = obj.id;
    amount = obj.amount;
}

//Destructor
Withdraw::~Withdraw()
{
}

//Functions
double Withdraw::makeWithdrawal(double balance) {
    if (balance > amount) {
        return balance - amount;
    }
    else {
        cancelTransaction();
        cout << "Amount exceeds balance.  Request denied.\n";
        return balance;
    }
}

Overloaded function (from Transaction)
void Withdraw::toString() {
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Transaction #" << id << endl;
    cout << "Withdrew $" << amount << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
}

//Overloaded = operator
const Withdraw Withdraw::operator=(const Withdraw &obj)
{
    id = obj.id;
    amount = obj.id;
    return *this;
}
```

Checks.cpp -- Checks is a derived class of Transactions

```
#include "Check.h"
#include<iostream>

//Constructor
Check::Check(double amt, string name)
{
    setAmount(amt);
    setName(name);
    checkNumber = ++numberedChecks;
}

//Copy Constructor
Check::Check(const Check &obj)
{
    id = obj.id;
    amount = obj.amount;
    checkNumber = obj.checkNumber;
    name = obj.name;
}

//Deconstructor
heck::~Check()
{
}

//Mutator Function
void Check::setCheckNumber(int number) {
    checkNumber = number;
}

void Check::setName(string newName) {
    name = newName;
}

//Other Functions
double Check::makeCheck(double balance)
{
    if (balance > amount)
        return balance - amount;
    else {
        cancelTransaction();
        cout << "If that check were to go through, you would have an overdraft.  Request denied.\n";
        return balance;
    }
}

//Overloaded Function (from Transaction)
void Check::toString() {
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Transition #" << id << endl;
    cout << "Check #" << checkNumber << endl;
    cout << "For the amount of $" << amount << endl;
    cout << "Made out to " << name << endl << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
}

//Overloaded = operator
const Check Check::operator= (const Check &obj)
{
    id = obj.id;
    amount = obj.amount;
    checkNumber = obj.checkNumber;
    name = obj.name;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem, that copy constructor weren't called or something else?

Comment: unrelated: `Transaction **pTemp = new Transaction*[++numberOfTransactions];` forces a resize on every addition. Consider increasing the size by more than one to reduce the number of resizes.

Comment: Unrelated: Lot of chaff in the code. Eg: `Transaction *tempTrans = pTransactions[i]; pTemp[i] = tempTrans;` could be `pTemp[i] = pTransactions[i];` Most egregious is `pTransactions = new Transaction*[numberOfTransactions];


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTransactions; i++) {
        pTransactions[i] = pTemp[i];
    }` Should probably just be `pTransactions = pTemp;` or something very similar.

Comment: I'm assuming the copy constructor isn't being called, i'm not sure why though.  pTemp[i] is just copying the address rather than the content.

Comment: `pTemp` is `Transaction **`. `pTemp[i]` is `Transaction *`. If you want to copy the contents you would need to dereference all of the pointers: `*pTemp[i]`.

Comment: Most of the chaff is me trying to figure this out ... I'll clean it up once the problem is solved ...

Comment: Don't add code while trying to debug. It only gives bugs more room to hide. Instead remove stuff. Make a back-up of your program, then start stripping it down until only the bug remains. Not only does it make it very easy to spot the bug, it makes it easier to run experiments to determine why it's a bug and figure out how best to fix it.  Handy reading: [mcve] and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: "I'm assuming the copy constructor isn't being called" - no need to assume, simply add some sort of unique cout into the copy ctor, and know.  (You can remove it later.)  Or, how about a break-point?  Maybe today is the day to discover how simple your debugger is.

Comment: I appreciate the help and suggestions.  Just to be clear, I know where the error is located, (Mr. Moen, I used break-points to pinpoint where my program had gone wrong).  I created this thread to (a) find out why it isn't working (maybe it is obvious, maybe it isn't) (b) what is my best option to get past this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
Something *a = new Something;
Something *b = a;
delete a;
```

In this code line 2 copy constructor for `Something` would not be called, you just assign one pointer to another, you do not copy objects. And when you destroy object pointed by `a` you cannot use `b` anymore as it is the same pointer as `a` ie it points to the same memory. You have this exact issue in your code:

```
if (*pTransactions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTransactions - 1; i++) {
        Transaction *tempTrans = pTransactions[i];
        pTemp[i] = tempTrans;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTransactions - 1; i++) {
        delete pTransactions[i];
    }
    delete[] pTransactions;
}
```

it is unclear why you expected copy ctor to be called and more important why you need it to be called, just do not destroy objects, only memory where pointers were stored.

This is not error but it is very ineffective to create temporary array, copy everything there and then copy into new one again. And increase array size by one is not a good idea either.

> What would be a better method?

Just move current pointer to temp, then allocate new one and copy pointers. Remember copying one pointer to another is simple operation (like assigning one `int` to another) but copying array is not:

```
Transaction **pTemp = pTRansactions;
pTransactions = new Transaction*[capacity];
if( pTemp )  {
   // copy existing transactions from pTemp to pTransactions
   delete[] pTemp;
}
// done
```

and you should have another member `capacity` and increase it by delta when size reaches it and execute this code in that case. You may want to have some policy to decrease capacity, but that can be omitted.

Comment: What would be a better method?

Comment: By the way, thank you.  I think I was getting confused with it being pointers and not the objects.  I found a way to get the code to work.  It was your simplification of what i was actually doing that help me the most ... so thank you.